# Tree pattern matching in rust gives strange cryptic errors

Tags: rust

I am not sure what is wrong:

I have an enum like the following:

```
#[derive(Debug,PartialEq)]
pub enum Tree {
    Leaf,
    Node(Box<Tree>,i32,Box<Tree>)
}
```

Now for some reason when I try to find the sum of all of the leaves in this tree:

```
pub fn tree_sum(t:&Tree) -> i32 {
    match t {
        Tree::Leaf => 0,
        Tree::Node(Leaf, x, Leaf) => *x

    }
}
```

The compiler decides to give me a very strange error:

```
error[E0416]: identifier `Leaf` is bound more than once in the same pattern
  --> src/functions.rs:11:28
   |
11 |         Tree::Node(Leaf,x, Leaf) => *x,
   |                            ^^^^ used in a pattern more than once
```

Can someone explain to me what went wrong and what it should be instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Tree::Node` variant contains types (`Box<Tree>`) which are not enums, meaning that you cannot match on the inner variants.

What's happening here is that, as the compiler tells you, you have created two different bindings with the same name.

If we assumed you're only interested in the contents of nodes, you'd do:

```
match t {
    Tree::Leaf => 0,
    Tree::Node(leaf1, x, leaf2) => ...
}
```

where both `leaf1` and `leaf2` being of the type `&Box<Tree>`.

Now it is a bit unclear what is the goal of this `match`, as if you were only interested in nodes containing two leaves, then this would make the `match` non-exhaustive, and you'd need to add default cases.

If you are not interested in the values of the inner trees, and only `*x` you can do the following:

```
match t {
    Tree::Leaf => 0,
    Tree::Node(_, x, _) => *x,
}
```

which is exhaustive.

If you want to match on nodes that contains two leaves, then you need to be more creative.
An example could be the following:

```
match t {
    Tree::Leaf => 0,
    Tree::Node(leaf1, x, leaf2)
        if matches!(**leaf1, Tree::Leaf) && matches!(**leaf2, Tree::Leaf) =>
    {
        *x
    }
    Tree::Node(_, _, _) => todo!()
}
```

Note that `leaf1` and `leaf2` are dereferenced twice in order to be unboxed.
This is needed because `t` is originally a reference.
A default pattern is also needed.

See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a0464766265b5fa3e9bf161fd9382c00).

Comment: For leaf1 and leaf2 I want them to be of type Tree::Leaf only, because I dont want to match Node(Node(_), x, Node(_)) how would i do that? Only match Node(Leaf, x Leaf)?

Comment: @chen I explained how to do it in the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Leaf is the name of a variable that is getting bound to part of that enum variant. You simply need to choose a different name for Leaf.

```rust
pub fn tree_sum(t:&Tree) -> i32 {
    match t {
        Tree::Leaf => 0,
        Tree::Node(Leaf, x, Leaf2) => *x
                          // ^^^ different name
    }
}
```